# Grails Plugin: Getting all command object classes

Tags: grails, plugins, command-objects

In a plugin, I need to iterate over all domain and command object classes to apply some meta-magic to them. Getting the domain classes isn't a problem, however command objects are not that easy to get hold of, since they don't seem to be considered Grails artefacts. After browsing the docs, I came up with the following code:

```
def doWithDynamicMethods = { ctx ->
    application.controllerClasses.each {
        it.commandObjectClasses.each {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work, however it **doesn't include the command objects that are used inside webflow actions**. Is this a bug or is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe commandObjects are true domainObjects.   You could use [the Artefact API](http://grails.org/Developer+-+Artefact+API) to register them and to find them.

Comment: Yes, I know that command objects are not domain classes and thus they are not included in `application.domainClasses`. That's why I'm looking for a way to get hold of the command objects. As to the Artefact API: To register the command objects as artefacts, I would still have to find all command objects in the first place (to be able to register them)...